# Cannot read property of 'uid' of null

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I need help, I used firebase as back-end and Ionic 4 as front-end.

I have error on console where when I first open/lunch the app, I received **Cannot read property of 'uid' of null** on console.

I read some related solutions but I haven't found one that solves my problem.

Below is the code when I implemented it in my app:

```
initializeApp() {

this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  const userId = user.uid;
  this.db.doc(`accounts/${userId}`).valueChanges().pipe(
    take(1)
  ).subscribe(userData => {
    const role = userData['role'];
    if (role == 'USER') {
      console.log('we got a customer user');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home')
    } else if (role == 'VENDOR') {
      console.log('we got a seller user');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/vendor-tabs/home-vendor')
    }
  })
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An auth state change listener is called when a user is **either** signed in and signed out. `user` will be null if not signed in. This means you have to check if `user` is truthy before you start accessing properties on it.

```
this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    // user is signed in
    const userId = user.uid;
  }
  else {
    // user is signed out - can't use properties of user.
  }
}
```

See the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#public-void-addauthstatelistener-firebaseauth.authstatelistener-listener).

Comment: If your solution was different, could you answer the question with the details?  Otherwise, please mark my answer as correct, so others might be helped by it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is **what I did to get rid of the cannot read property of 'uid' null**.

```
this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    const userId = user.uid;
    this.db.doc(`accounts/${userId}`).valueChanges().pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(userData => {
      const role = userData['role'];
      if (role == 'USER') {
        console.log('we got a customer user');
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home')
      } else if (role == 'VENDOR') {
        console.log('we got a seller user');
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/vendor-tabs/home-vendor')
      }
    })
  } else {
    return of(null);
  }
})
```